# Same class buttons react differently on taps

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I want to build an expandable button, like a picker. Tap on that button will show options to choose from. For some reason, option buttons don't recognize touches.
Here is it main button that is used widely in the app. The passed action triggered in `touchesEnded`. I do some other stuff like feedback and animation in `touchesBegan`

```
class RoundButton: UIButton {

    private let action: (()->())

    init(action: @escaping ()->()) {
        self.action = action
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        action()
    }
}
```

Base wiew that has `RoundButton` and options which are also `RoundButton`

```
class ExpandableRoundButton: UIView {
    
    private var children: [RoundButton] = []
    private lazy var main: RoundButton = {
        RoundButton(action: { [ weak self] in
            self?.didTapMainButton()
        })
    }()

    init(children: [RoundButton]) {
        self.children = children
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    private func didTapMainButton() {
        if children.first?.transform == .identity {
            expand()
        } else {
            collapse()
        }
    }
    
    func expand() {
        let spacing: CGFloat = 16
        children.enumerated().forEach { index, button in
            button.isHidden = false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn]) {
                let translation = (button.frame.width + spacing) * CGFloat(index + 1)
                button.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translation, y: 0)
            } completion: { _ in }
        }
    }
    
    func collapse() {
        children.enumerated().forEach { _, button in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn]) {
                button.transform = .identity
            } completion: { _ in
                button.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the implementation of the above base view. The issue that children's buttons are not recognizing taps. The tap goes to the next responder. Don't understand how that's possible because children and the main button are the same types.

```
class SelectColorRoundButton: ExpandableRoundButton {
    
    init(action: @escaping (UIColor)->()) {
        
        let children: [RoundButton] = DrawingColor.allCases.map { color in
            let button = RoundButton(image: UIImage(), action: { action(color.color) })

            return button
        }
        super.init(children: children)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you edit your question and add enough code to run an example, it will be easier to help. But, almost certainly, you are positioning your buttons **outside** the view's bounds. Look at [hitTest()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest).

Comment: Thanks, @DonMag. You were right. I changed the frame for a button. because it was always as initial